# How does one save a modified PyPDF2 object and write out the new, modified PDF to drive?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have constructed a pdf editor that can modify a PDF in-place in fairly robust fashion.

Only one problem: when running `PyPDF2`, I can only call `setData` in a `DecodedStreamObject` or `EncodedStreamObject` under certain -- but not all -- conditions.

How do I ensure, for a particular pdf, that the `DecodedStreamObject` instances exposed by `pypdf2` are settable?

This could be by:

- reading the pdf into memory entirely
- creating a temporary pdf with all permissions
- ... or anything in between

The basic point is there is some happy path where a pdf's stream objects are settable; however, I am not sure what that state is or how to ensure that state is present every time.

---

To make this question more concrete, here is the pattern of code I am using to modify the pdf page:

```
### get the content
pdf_content = page.getContents()

### adjust the contents...
data = pdf_content.get_data()
encoding = chardet.detect(data)['encoding']
decoded_data = data.decode(encoding)
success, fn_output = fn(decoded_data)
if success and decoded_data != fn_output:
     fn_output_encoded = fn_output.encode(encoding)
     if pdf_content.decoded_self is not None:
         pdf_content.decoded_self.set_data(fn_output_encoded)
     else:
         pdf_content.set_data(fn_output_encoded)  # not yet supported
return success, pdf_content

### and updating the page...
success, new_contents = cls.data_processor(page.getContents(), cls.subst_fn(subst_expressions), global_=True)

page[NameObject('/Contents')] = new_contents

writer.addPage(page)
```

Comment: @KJ I am not sure that makes sense.  I have a PyPDF2 streaming extraction from the hard drive which is read onto a PyPDF2 writer.  I modify decoded structural pdf data in plaintext form and plop it back into the PyPDF2 Decoded Stream Object.  I have detected (and PR'd) a bug in the Decoded Stream Object.  However, the PyPDF2 Object does not write out to file as it has been set in the case of *some* but *not all* pdfs I have tested.  The idea here is to make it work for all, and so your comment sounds deep and knowledgeable at some levels, but it is not helpful.

Comment: @KJ I appreciate it, as there aren't many of us who have spent enough time on PDFs to wind up asking this kind of question.  But this is really a PyPDF2 question disguised as a PDF question.

Comment: @KJ And in fairness I'll need to modify the question significantly from its "high level" state.  But I am at work and onto a work around.

Comment: My knowledge of PDF internals is VERY limited - I guess you probably know more than I do. This is the reason why I wanted to increase test coverage before I start merging more complex PRs into PyPDF2. However, if there is a missing feature: Feel free to open a PR :-) pubpub-zz on github currently is on fire 

Comment: @MartinThoma lol awesome -- I'll see if I can't get it working again

Comment: Always when I read this title I think it's about https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/streaming-data.html 

Comment: @MartinThoma I'll update it :)